# "Unlink" Windows 8.1 key before fresh install of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-installation

I purchased a Windows 8.1 software key after the release of the OS and have been using it on my installation of 8.1. I'd like to do a fresh install of Windows 10, and am using the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to do so. During the process, I will of course be formatting the hard drive, so the previous OS (and any other data for that matter) will not be present during the Windows 10 install.

Do I have to "unlink", or do anything of the sort with my Windows 8.1 key before I can use it again with my fresh Windows 10 installation?

Comment: Don't format & install, you'll lose your free upgrade. Upgrade, then do a reset.

Comment: Can anyone find the existing duplicate question?

Comment: You surrender your W8 key when you agree to the free upgrade, free is not always free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do an upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

If you want to do a clean Installation you could choose that during the upgrade. You have three different Options:

1. clean install
2. Keep your personal settings and files
3. Keep your personal settings, files and apps